# Dynamics CRM Project Service Automation Install in sandbox environment

Tags: dynamics-crm

Project Service Automation application is not displayed in the sandbox Dynamics 365  environment.

So far I have installed the Project Service Automation application via enabling it on the applications screen in the Dynamics 365 admin screen.

Have I missed a step to enable the application?

Additionally the Project Service Automation roles and solutions have not been added to the Dynamics CRM instance.

Answer (score 0):

Once you click `Install` option of PSA solution for your CRM instance in O365 admin center, the status will turn into 'Installation Pending'. It may take a while to install the components in CRM & status changed into 'Installed' [Read this for detailed steps](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/crmandunifiedservicedesk/archive/2016/06/04/project-service-automation-trial-install-and-configure)

Make sure to complete the [prerequisite configurations](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics/crm-customer-center/configure-dynamics-365-for-project-service-automation.aspx) to finish the setup.

- Time Units
- Organizational Units
- Price Lists
- Invoice Frequency
- Transactional Categories
- Expense Categories
- Product Catalog
- Resources

If you still didn't find the sitemap of PSA, after solution says installed look @ [bookmark](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn973004.aspx) for how to check Service health & raise a service request.